# javascript how to convert number 1.0 to string "1.0"?

Tags: javascript

I used to use `String` function to convert number to string, but I found for the case like 1.0, the result is "1" but I expect to "1.0". I know 1 and 1.0 are essentially the same in Javascript. but how do you usually patch it to support my case?

UPDATE:
Please don't misunderstand my question that I want to keep the other default behavior of `String` which means `toFixed` is not right solution.
e.g.

```
1 ==> "1"
1.0 ==> "1.0"
1.00 ==> "1.00"
1.2334 ==> "1.2334"
```

Comment: There's no way to distinguish between `1` and `1.0`. Hence there's no function that would convert both `1` to `"1"` and `1.0` to `"1.0"` without some additional information.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "toFixed" function to do that, e.g.:

```
var num = 1.2345;
var n = num.toFixed(1);
```

You can combine this with a check to see if the number is an integer:

```
function numToString(num)
{
    if (num % 1 === 0) 
        return num.toFixed(1);
    else
        return num.toString();
}
```

Comment: That's not right! I want to keep the default behavior which means  5.56789 should convert to "5.56789"

Comment: @LeoShi `(5.56789).toString()` will return `"5.56789"` anyway.

Comment: @AaditMShah sure, but how to make a common function to support all of these case?

Comment: @LeoShi There's no way to support all of these cases without some additional information because there's no way to distinguish between `1` and `1.0` in JavaScript. Hence there's no function which returns `"1"` for `1` and `"1.0"` for `1.0` without some additional information.

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your answer, but what about 1.00 then 1.000?

Comment: @LeoShi `(1).toFixed(2)` and `(1).toPrecision(3)` respectively.

Comment: That's not possible - JavaScript doesn't know about those extra zeroes in a numeric field, as Aadit M Shah mentioned above.

Comment: @LeoShi So what is your so-called "all of these case"? You don't provide the information, nobody knows what you really want.

Comment: This also doesn't provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible without reading the source code since `1`, `1.0`, `1.00` etc all evaluate to 1.

Answer (score -1):

What about a really dirty and quick solution:

```
var x = 1.23456;
var str = "" + x;

console.log( str );
console.log( typeof str );
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for the case of 1.0. It will not convert ' '+1.0  to '1.0'